# InAppBrowser does not open properly with iOS 10.2 (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios10, inappbrowser

I've been using the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin for a long time now and when I updated the software to 10.2.1 on my apple test devices the plugin no longs works properly. When I try to open the inappbrowser link nothings happens unless I click the home button and return to the app. This happens for the simulators as well as on real devices like ipad, iphone 5s, iphone 6 and iphone 7. it works fine on android devices just not the latest iOS.

Here's a list of everything i tried:

- updated inappbrowser to latest version - 1.7.1
- removed and reinstalled the plugin and ios platform
- tried making a blank app with the inappbrowser plugin
- tried changing the index.html meta tag to include gap:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * &apos;self&apos; gap: ; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *; child-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *;">
  ```

I can't seem to find anything else to try as most posts I do find that have a similar issue haven't been answered.

Below is the relevant code to how the inappbrowser plugin was installed and is being used:

**config.xml Structure**

```
<widget>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <preference/> 
  ...
  <feature name="StatusBar">
  ...
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
  ... icons and splash ...
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1"/>
</widget>
```

**Using plugin in Controller**

```
$scope.showLink = function(url){
  var options = {
   location: 'yes'
  }
  $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options)
  .then(function(event){
    // success
    console.log('inappbrowser', event);
  })
  .catch (function(event) {
   // error
   console.log('inappbrowser error', event);
  });
};

$scope.openUrl = function(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
};
```

I'm using ionic v1.7.14 , cordova: 6.2.0 and xcode 8

Comment: Same problem here, seems not only in-app-browser is heaving trouble displaying on top of instance. I've noticed that also permission alert is not appearing. After I click home button I can see permission popup as well as in-app-browser. I would recommend downgrading xcode to latest working version.

Comment: you can try `Content-Security-Policy` that Im using: it worked for me:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data:; script-src 'self' maps: tel: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost; media-src *" />
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by CodeGems, in the comments, adding `gap://ready` to your `Content-Security-Policy` should fix the issue.